# how to set up cors() in typescript express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, cors

In one of my projects, simply this worked:

```
import cors from "cors";

server.use(cors());
```

but currently, I am having this lovely typescript warning message in my new project:

```
  No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request<never, never, never, never>, res: { statusCode?: number | undefined; setHeader(key: string, value: string): any; end(): any; }, next: (err?: any) => any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
      Type '(req: Request<never, never, never, never>, res: { statusCode?: number | undefined; setHeader(key: string, value: string): any; end(): any; }, next: (err?: any) => any) => void' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
        Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
          Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>' is not assignable to type 'Request<never, never, never, never>'.
            Type 'ParamsDictionary' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2769)
```

then I tried to set up custom cors middleware and use it:

```
import { NextFunction ,Request,Response} from 'express';

export const Cors=(req:Request, res:Response, next:NextFunction) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
      return res.sendStatus(200);
    }
    next();
  };

   server.use(Cors());
```

this time i am having another lovely error :

No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type 'Response | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found this solution:

Using:

```json
...
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
...
```

replace ".use(cors())" for

```
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  next();
}, cors({ maxAge: 84600 }));
```

Source: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/43909#issuecomment-743156647

Comment: Looks like I used your solution back then with adding types for `req`, `res` and `next`

Answer (score 13):

This is because of some ambiguity in the generic typing for the cors library. The easiest way I've found to fix this is simply explicitly specify the request type for the `cors` method.

```
import { Request } from "express";
import cors from "cors";

server.use(cors<Request>());
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

```json
{
  "cors": "^2.8.5",
  "express": "^4.18.1",
  "typescript": "^4.8.4",
}
```

it works:

```js
import cors = require("cors");
```

```js
app.use(cors<Request>());
```

Answer (score 0):

An update in the same thread,

```
app.use((cors as (options: cors.CorsOptions) => express.RequestHandler)({}));
```

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/43909#issuecomment-1168194740